# Vertx Eventbus client with Scala.js

Tags: vert.x, scala.js, scalajs-react

I'm trying to create a new Vertx Eventbus instance in Scala.js project. No matter what I do, I get INVALID_STATE_ERR when trying to register handler in onopen function.

It seems like the onopen is being fired prematurely.

Example code:
Eventbus.scala:

```
@js.native
@JSImport("vertx3-eventbus-client",JSImport.Default)
class Eventbus(url:String) extends js.Any{

def registerHandler(address:String,callback:
(js.Dynamic,js.Dynamic)=>Unit): Nothing =js.native

var onopen:Unit=js.native
```

}

Then, from my app, I call it:

```
    val eb = new Eventbus("http://localhost:8080/eventbus")
    eb.onopen={
    println("opening")
    eb.registerHandler("activity-updates", (err, mess) => {
      val message = mess.body.toString
      println(message)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your typing of `onopen` is wrong. It should probably be `js.Function0[Unit]`.

What happens is that the code in `onopen` is executed immediately (rather than "on open").

Change to this:

```
var onopen: js.Function0[Unit]=js.native

eb.onopen={ () =>
println("opening")
eb.registerHandler("activity-updates", (err, mess) => {
  val message = mess.body.toString
  println(message)
})
```

The reason `registerHandler` got executed immediately is that Scala (in general) allows statements (and therefore blocks) in expression position.

So if we just look at the assignment to `ep.onopen`:

```
eb.onopen={
  println("opening")
  eb.registerHandler("activity-updates", (err, mess) => {
    val message = mess.body.toString
    println(message)
  })
}
```

This assigns the result of the block on the right hand side (of value `Unit`) to `eb.onopen`. Practically this means that statements get executed like this:

```
println("opening")
val tmp = eb.registerHandler("activity-updates", (err, mess) => {
  val message = mess.body.toString
  println(message)
})

eb.onopen=tmp
```

So you can see that `registerHandler` gets executed even before `onopen` is even assigned. This feature (statements in expression position) is of course rarely useful for things returning `Unit`. However, there are cases where it is extremely useful. For example, temporaries:

```
val x = {
  val myHelper = ???
  if (myHelper) ???
  else ???
}
```

Now `myHelper` does not escape in scope and it is clear that it was only useful to calculate `x` and not used anymore later.

Comment: You are right, thanks! But why was it executed immediately?

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful.